# Filtrar dataset com Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataset, ipython-notebook

Estou querendo filtrar um dataset usando duas condições, porém quando pego esse filtro, eu não consigo armazenar ele, pois ele acaba retornando um objeto e não um array de boolean.Não consegui fazer a conversão.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn.model_selection as ms
import sklearn.linear_model as lm
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

data = pd.read_csv("./sample_data/Cleaned_Laptop_data.csv")
filtro = data[(data['ratings'] > 0 ) & (data['old_price'] > 0)]
data = data[filtro]
data
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: tá vazio o csv?

Comment: não, o csv não está vazio

Comment: Opaaa Lolzeiro, poderia dá um df.head() ou mostrar o arquivo csv para nós ter uma leitura melhor do que se trata o dataframe?

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Resolvi!
apenas mudei
isso:

```
data = data[filtro]
```

para isso:

```
data = filtro
```